# Is there a way to show Email content only on Outlook Browser?

Tags: email, outlook, conditional-comments, outlook.com

Is there a way to show email content only on Outlook.com (the browser version) and hide for the rest?

Example:

```
<!--[if !mso]><!-- -->
    Show this for all platforms except Outlook Desktop
<!--<![endif]-->

<!-- -->
    Hide this for all platforms except Outlook Browser
<!-- -->
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

There is no trivial to get such functionality out of the box. The Outlook object model, nor the editor, doesn't provide anything for that. However, you can develop an Outlook add-in (former Mail App) which can be run on the web and display the message body. See [Outlook add-ins](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-add-ins?product=outlook) for more information.